# How can I remove the 300ms delay on Angular routerLink using Hammer.js?

Tags: angular, cordova, hammer.js, routerlink

I am trying to remove the famous 300ms delay from my app with `Hammer.js`, and have been successful so far using `tap` in stead of `click`.

However, this does not work on `routerLink`'s. I haven't found any articles or other people writing about this issue, so I hope you can help.

The app is made with Angular and Cordova.

Is there a way to remove the 300ms delay on `routerLinks`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Ionic's troubleshooting guide on tap and click, I found that the best solution to this issue would be to use `(click)` **with** `tapable` in front of it.

See Ionic doc [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/#click-delays) (sadly, the link is not working at the moment, but I will post it anyway, for future reference, hoping they haven't removed it from the docs compoletely).

Also here is the [forum post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/click-vs-tap/99094) that let me to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

A work around can be to do the navigation pragmatically on `(tap)` event.

Comment: Which poses a really big a11y and UX issue as links aren't links anymore and things like open in new tab won't work.

Comment: it's a cordova app, it doesn't have `open in new tab` behavior. Links aren't really meant to be links, they are links which are pretending to be native buttons with navigation actions. @IngoBürk

Comment: what does this mean for my app?

Comment: @Lirianna If you are only releasing the app on mobile then it's not a problem at all, we already do that in ionic. But if you are releasing it on desktop too as a web application, then you will have to do some workarounds to fix the UX

Comment: @Zahema Thank you for your answers. The app is only running on Android and iOS. I will take a look into my click delay or maybe/hopefully lack thereof.